# how to handling non English chars with php

Tags: php, encoding, charts, character-encoding, char

I have code in php that create file with name that user input like below

html

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="file">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

php

```
$file = $_POST['file'].'.php';
$f = fopen($file, 'w');
fclose($f);
```

the problem appear when user use non-english chars 
example user input = اللغة العربيه

resault = ظ…ط±ط§ظ‡ظ‚ظˆ-ط§ظ„طھط§ظٹطھظ†ط.php

but it should be = اللغة العربيه.php

Comment: Problem could be with filesystem. What filesystem you are using, or if you don't know that, at least your operating system?

Comment: my operating system is windows , I dont know what is my file system

Answer (score 0):

Trying to create files with non-english filenames can be quite hard.

Easiest solution is to not use such filenames at all, but encode all filenames e.g. with `urlencode`:

```
$filename = $_POST['file'].'.php';
$encoded_filename = urlencode($filename);
$f = fopen($encoded_filename, 'w');
fclose($f);
```

This will not affect English characters and will allow creating filenames using any language.

Note that each filesystem will have some limits on how long filesnames can be, so if `$encoded_filename` becomes too long this will not work.

Comment: thanx for ur answer ,but I realy need file name to be with the original user input